# Does $cN \leq \left|\sum_{n= 1}^{N}f(n)\right|$ imply $|f(n)| \geq c/2$ for many $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function potentially taking negative values. Suppose I knew that $$cN \leq \left|\sum_{n= 1}^{N}f(n)\right|$$ for some absolute constant $c$. Then by the Pigeonhole Principle, there is at least one integer $n_0 \in [1, N]$ such that $|f(n_0)| \geq c/2$. Can I say more? Do I know that a positive proportion of the integers $n \in [1, N]$ satisfy $|f(n)|\geq c/2$?

Comment: Is $N$ fixed or not?

Comment: $N$ is fixed and large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $N$ is fixed in the problem, the answer is no. For example $f(N)=cN$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise has the required property.

Even if the statement holds for "many" $N$, it should be easy to construct examples where the function is zero at most points and takes very large values at few points.

**P.S.** Originally you requested $f$ to be multiplicative. Even so, it is easy to construct such examples. Pick $p$ to be the largest prime less than $N$. Then $f(k)=cN$ if $p|k$ and $1$ otherwise satisfies the required conditions.